# Spark streaming with python: how to add a UUID column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, uuid

I would like to add a column with a generated id to my data frame. I have tried:

```
uuidUdf = udf(lambda x: str(uuid.uuid4()), StringType())
df = df.withColumn("id", uuidUdf())
```

however, when I do this, nothing is written to my output directory. When I remove these lines, everything works fine so there must be some error but I don't see anything in the console.

I have tried using monotonically_increasing_id() instead of generating a UUID but in my testing, this produces many duplicates. I need a unique identifier (does not have to be a UUID specifically).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13):

A simple way:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.range(10)
df.withColumn("uuid", f.expr("uuid()")).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: This is actually faster than @PavithranRamachandran answer

Comment: Missing the `asNondeterministic`

Comment: @DannyVarod, no it's not missing anything. We're using a (nondeterministic) Spark SQL expression here, not a UDF. There's no reason to run asNondeterministic; in fact that would probably just cause an error.

Answer (score 12):

Please Try this:

```
import uuid
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

uuidUdf= udf(lambda : str(uuid.uuid4()),StringType())
Df1 = Df.withColumn("id",uuidUdf())
```

**Note:** You should assign to new DF after adding new column. (*Df1 = Df.withColumn(....)*

Comment: it seems that uuidUdf() passed to withColumn function gives a " assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column" " error. any thoughts?

Comment: @Atanuchatterjee UDFs works times (or even tens of times) slower in Python. It's especially important for Streaming. Better use vectorized Pandas UDFs or Scala UDFs

Comment: applying this solution can lead to unwanted results. Every-time an operation is applied on Df1, the values for id will be different.

Comment: @AlessioG this is the only result that makes sense for UUID - they are supposed to be unique (different) per row, per run, per machine, per timestamp etc.

Comment: @DannyVarod you are totally right on the definition. My comment was to warn about unwanted results/side effects. You can't rely on `Df1` to always have the same uuids throughout your code, because values change as you apply operations on it

Comment: @AlessioG true, if you iterate the results twice you'll get different results, therefore if you have to process twice, you should persist after adding the random column.

Comment: Is there ever a good reason to use the java util instead [example here](https://gitlab.com/akkasali910/companieshouse-data/-/blob/master/compare_records.py#L90)?

Answer (score 7):

From `pyspark`'s `functions.py`:

> note: The user-defined functions are considered deterministic by default. Due to optimization, duplicate invocations may be eliminated or the function may even be invoked more times than it is present in the query. If your function is not deterministic, call `asNondeterministic` on the user defined function. E.g.:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
import random
random_udf = udf(lambda: int(random.random() * 100), IntegerType()).asNondeterministic()
```

So for a UUID this would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import uuid
random_udf = udf(lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), StringType()).asNondeterministic()
```

and the usage:

```
df = df.withColumn('id', random_udf())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `lit` function so that you generate same id for all the records.
`lit` performs the function only once and gets the column value and adds it to every record.

```
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+---+
|x  |
+---+
|0  |
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|4  |
|5  |
|6  |
|7  |
|8  |
|9  |
+---+
>>> import uuid
>>> id = str(uuid.uuid4())
>>> df = df.withColumn("id", lit(id))
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+---+------------------------------------+
|x  |id                                  |
+---+------------------------------------+
|0  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|1  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|2  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|3  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|4  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|5  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|6  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|7  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|8  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
|9  |923b69d6-4bee-423d-a892-79162df5684d|
+---+------------------------------------+
```

Using `udf` won't solve the function as it gets called for every row, and we end up getting new uuid's for each call.

```
>>> df1 = df.withColumn("id",uuidUdf())
>>> uuidUdf= udf(lambda : str(uuid.uuid4()),StringType())
>>> df1 = df.withColumn("id",uuidUdf())
>>> df1.show(truncate=False)
+---+------------------------------------+
|x  |id                                  |
+---+------------------------------------+
|0  |6d051ec6-b91a-4c42-b37c-707a293f1dc8|
|1  |cd3c75b1-8a06-461b-82ae-51f4354296bd|
|2  |3996a022-de99-4403-9346-74e66210f9ef|
|3  |ad57a9c4-5c67-4545-bef6-77d89cff70d5|
|4  |5c9a82a1-323e-4ce0-9082-e36c5a6f61db|
|5  |7a64ee81-4c84-43d0-ab7d-0a79ed694950|
|6  |a0fb26e7-cf1a-445d-bd26-10dc453ddc1e|
|7  |435a7e6a-da22-4add-8953-b5c56b01c790|
|8  |fd3c5fd8-c9d5-4725-b32a-f3ce9386b9b8|
|9  |2291cc67-47cf-4921-80ec-b4180c73533c|
+---+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, you want a unique id for each record, that's why they're called uuids.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using `pyspark= "==3.2.1"`, you can add your uuid [version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) easly like the following

```
import uuid
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn("uuid", f.lit(str(uuid.uuid4())))
```

### Update

It seems that I ended up using an UDF function

```py
import uuid
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# convert function to UDF
uuidUdf = f.udf(lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), StringType())

df.withColumn("uuid", uuidUdf())
```

Comment: `TypeError: col should be Column`

Comment: Don't use this one, it will create an identical id for all the rows.