# Pyspark - generate a distinct values when adding a new column to a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to add new `uuid` column but I want to have a distinct value for each line in the dataframe

```
 df = (
        df.withColumn("uuid", f.lit(str(uuid.uuid4())))
```

We can encounter this by using `create_map` ! However, is there a better way to do so ?

Comment: And I mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483584/1374437) in particular, not your :)

Comment: @HristoIliev yeah ! it should works using UDF